# Shared Resource (TWI/ADC) - Message Queue's or Mutex's

Tags: synchronization, embedded, serial-port

I wrote a driver for an ADC which used a Mutex in the read() function to cause threads to block if the ADC was already in use.

I currently have employed the same method for reading back data on the TWI interface.

I've seen Message Queue's used for queuing messages to be sent on the TWI interface. But if you are trying to read back data - you'd be wanting to wait for the response anyway. So, wouldn't the Mutex approach be more appropriate?

Could people provide their thoughts on what approach I should use? Pros/cons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queueing up request/response objects to one thread that runs the interface is more complex but more flexible - it can allow synchronous and asynchronous exchanges with the same mechanism.  Threads that need a protocol exchange have a choice - they can wait on some synchro object  for the interface-thread to signal that a response has been received, or provide their own reply-queue mechanism so that multiple requests can be queued up to the interface thread and replies queued back when each is done.  I usually provide an 'OnCompletion(thisRRobject)', function/method in the RR class that the interface thread calls when done, so delegating the actual reply action to code in the requesting thread/s.  The RR object can also contain members for exception/error messages, timeout intervals etc. Such complication is fine in a library, giving the users the widest choice of comms.

..or you could just use a mutex.  Simple, but synchronous only - every requesting thread has to wait if a previous exchange is in progress.  If a requsting thread does not want to wait/block, tough.

Horses for courses...